# Render FlatList of Videos in a performant way

Tags: react-native, expo, video-streaming

I am using a react native with expo. I have a lot of videos that I need to render (sort of like TikTok does). When I fetch about 30 videos and put them in the flat list in the `renderItem` method, it gets stuck and luggish. I was thinking about getting an amount of videos but sending to the renderItem method only 3 videos each time, and when the user will scroll down and reach index 2 it will shift the first index and append the fourth video from the fetched one. The idea was to have a small array of size 3 and change the items in it every scroll, in order to prevent rendering all the videos at once. That required array manipulation and caused a rerender each time the array of videos was updated(each change made sort of a flash - what was indicating a whole rerender).
My question is how should it be implemented in order the transition between the videos to be as fast and clean as possible from the client side perspective? What is the correct way to render videos in a flat list so it won't be stuck? I dont think It should be done that way, there has to be a better way.

This is what I have tried:
// challenges is an array coming from a fetch, just sliced it for the purpose of the example
// suppose it is an array that contains 30 items
const [currentVideos, setCurrentVideos] = useState([challenges.slice(0,3)]);

```
<FlatList
        data={currentVideos}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(challenge, i) => challenge._id}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        snapToInterval={Dimensions.get("window").height - UIConsts.bottomNavbarHeight}
        snapToAlignment={"start"}
        decelerationRate={"fast"}
        ref={(ref) => {
          flatListRef.current = ref;
        }}
        onScrollToIndexFailed={() => alert("no such index")}
        onViewableItemsChanged={onViewRef.current}
        onScrollEndDrag={() => (scrollEnded.current = true)}
        onScrollBeginDrag={beginDarg}
      ></FlatList>

  useEffect(() => {
// just wanted to check on 3 videos
         if (currentlyPlaying === 2) {
           let temp = currentVideos;
           temp.shift(); // pop the top item
           temp.push(challenges[4]) // append a new one
           setCurrentVideos(temp);
         }
      }, [currentlyPlaying]);


 const onViewRef = useRef(({ viewableItems }) => {
    // change playing video only after user stop dragging
    scrollEnded.current && setCurrentlyPlaying(viewableItems[0]?.index);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I would avoid manipulating the `data` array and doing business logic inside of the component.
   Besides, you can achieve your desired behaviour without the need to manipulate your `data` array at all, with the [`maxToRenderPerBatch`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration#maxtorenderperbatch) `FlatList` prop. As mentioned in the official RN docs for [FlatList optimization techniques](https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration).
2. You should avoid using anonymous functions and objects inside of your component's `properties`, move them outside of the return statement and use the `useMemo` and `useCallback` hooks to avoid their unnecessary recreation on every re-render. For example instead of writing your code like this:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <FlatList
      keyExtractor={(challenge, i) => challenge._id}
      snapToInterval={Dimensions.get('window').height - UIConsts.bottomNavbarHeight}
    />
  );
};
```

A better approach would be to re-write it to something like this:

```
const App = () => {
  // Because of useCallback, the keyExtractor function will be memoized and won't recreate itself on every re-render
  const keyExtractor = useCallback((challenge, i) => challenge._id, []);

  // useMemo is almost the same as useCallback, but it is used to return non-function types
  // Defining your snapToInterval variable like this will cause it to memoize its value and it
  // won't recreate itself on every re-render
  const snapToInterval = useMemo(() => Dimensions.get('window').height - UIConsts.bottomNavbarHeight, []);

  return (
    <FlatList
      keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
      snapToInterval={snapToInterval}
    />
  );
};
```

If you haven't already, you should consider extracting the component returned from  the `renderItem` function to a different file and applying [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) to it.

**Note: try not to overuse `useCallback` and `useMemo`. You can find good and detailed explanation of why not to overuse them [here](https://dmitripavlutin.com/dont-overuse-react-usecallback/) and [here](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback).**

3. If you're able to, you should optimize your videos before uploading them to the server. You can optimize your client side part of the app as much as you want, but if the content isn't properly optimized, you won't be able to achieve a smooth and performant experience regardless of your efforts.

Here's also some articles describing how you can optimize your `FlatList` component:

- [How did I optimize my React Native FlatList?](https://medium.com/@giomodiogo/how-did-i-optimize-my-react-native-flatlist-edbc54acc231)
- [8 ways to optimize React native FlatList performance](https://codingislove.com/optimize-react-native-flatlist-performance/)
- [Optimizing a React Native FlatList With Many Child Components](https://www.g2i.co/blog/optimizing-a-react-native-flatlist-with-many-child-components)
- [React Native Performance Optimisation With Hooks](https://dev.to/ltsharma/performance-optimisation-react-native-with-hooks-a77)
- [React Native: Optimized FlatList of videos](https://medium.com/@jenshandersson/react-native-optimized-flatlist-of-videos-bb048cb696db)

I hope that some of this will be helpful to you. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks so much on the detailed answer, I will try that. Any suggestions on how to optimize the videos on the server side? I just upload them and send them back to the client with express as static files

Comment: By the way, max bideo size is like 10mb, is that considered to be significant?

Comment: I am not sure how exactly you can optimize videos in `express js`, but maybe the [`node-opencv`](https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv) library could be used for that. But you can use [this](https://github.com/shahen94/react-native-video-processing) package to optimize the video with RN on the client side.
And the max video size of 10MB shouldn't be that significant.

Comment: Btw [`here`](https://medium.com/@jenshandersson/react-native-optimized-flatlist-of-videos-bb048cb696db) is another article explaining how to optimize a `FlatList` of videos.

Comment: I will read everything thanks a lot again for your help! Unfortunately this package cannot be used with expo..

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for a solution as well. I have worked out a solution based on some previous work using InViewPort. you can check it out here https://github.com/471Q/React-Native-FlatList-Video-Feed

Comment: The InViewport method is terrible unfortunately. Just a single FlatList view with InViewport drops JS FPS fom 60 to constant 30-40 on a high end iPhone device. The setInterval methods used for it should be avoided. onVisibileItemsChanged should be the way to go